# Button not showing android studio

Tags: android-studio

If i put the button before appbar it does not show up. If i put it inside, it shows up but it does not fit properly (height is under imageview and the two can not be in the same height). I tried different layouts other than coordinatorlayout and it hapens again there too.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:alpha="1"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/search_button"
        android:layout_width="55.5dp"
        android:layout_height="55.5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="298.5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_search_24" />

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="155dp"
            android:layout_height="55.5dp"
            android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_banner_foreground" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:tabGravity="center"
            app:tabMode="auto" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="59dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="672dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="566dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="566dp" />
    </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to have posted more code than what would be reasonable for your issue. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mre]; providing a MRE helps users answer your question and future users relate to your issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is not showing because you've used "@android:color/transparent" as background for your ImageButton. Chose another color and it will be visible. Or just add some text so that you can see it.

Comment: android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_search_24" />
Background is supposed to be transparent and the search icon is seen on preview WHEN it is under appbar!

Comment: i appreciate your attempt but i think you need to read things more carefully.